# Defer or Async fb chat

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous, deferred

I'va added the FB chat on my website with this short code :

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v6.0'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your customer chat code -->
  <div class="fb-customerchat"
    attribution=setup_tool
    page_id="366112410637632"
    theme_color="#44bec7"
    logged_in_greeting="Bonjour, si vous avez la moindre question, je suis disponible pour vous aider !"
    logged_out_greeting="Bonjour, si vous avez la moindre question, je suis disponible pour vous aider !">
  </div>
```

But it's kinda heavy during the loading and yslow tells me that I should defer or async it, I tried to add the defer to the   but it does not seem to work.
I'm a bit newb on js how can I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Embedding this the same way as the normal SDK should probably work, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#loading (note that the script sources are different.) Facebook used to suggest a code similar to the one above for the normal SDK, but that included also explicitly setting the async attribute, IIRC. They seem to have switched to a simpler version now, probably because browser support for async/defer is broader now, than it used to be.

Comment: So I should add defer async in <script> like : <script defer async> ? As it doesn't seems to work I still have this issue on GTMetrix : https://ibb.co/6F4Ghmc

Comment: That appears to not even be the SDK itself, but the additional scripts it loads in return. Maybe using a timeout to trigger the initial embed code a bit later might help?

Comment: I did that and it's ok ! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the question but the solution that works for me in 2020 (and with the facebook pixel) is wrapping the facebook script in a timeout function:

so the code facebook gives you for your chat plugin is:

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v8.0'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
  <div class="fb-customerchat"
    attribution=setup_tool
    page_id="xxxxxxx" theme_color="#BB1C1C">
  </div>
```

I then wrap it like so:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v8.0'
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}, 4500);
</script>
<div class="fb-customerchat" attribution=setup_tool page_id="1429606483967175" 
theme_color="#BB1C1C"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! You mean the solution above may cause troubles with pixel ?